# Angular magnification of three lenses telescope?

Tags: telescope

What is the magnification of a three-lens telescope?

As a child I built a "telescope": objective lens $$f_1 = 20 cm$$ middle lens $$f_2=5cm$$ and eye lens also $$f_3=5cm$$

My drawing of my telescope:

[image: my drawing of tetlescope]

I measured the magnification "with my eyes". It was about 10x-15x.

But what's the formula?

I had found a formula for a terrestrial telescope, but it doesn't really help. It is said that the middle lens is "only used to correct" the image. Then the magnification should be done like a "normal" telescope ([see link](https://www.studyadda.com/notes/jee-main-advanced/physics/ray-optics/terrestrial-telescope/8757)):

$$
f_ {objectiveLens} / f_ {eyesLens}
$$

In my telescope, the magnification was dependent on the distance between the middle and eye lenses: larger distance -> bigger magnification.

**UPDATE 1:**
My idea was calculate magnification of objective like
$$
25/f_{objective}
$$
Then calculate magnification for system of middle and eye lenses like for microscope (here: [link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/micros.html)). And then multiply both magnifications.

Here is my calculations (see drawing):

Magnification of objective:
$$
m_{objective} = 25cm/f_{1}=25cm/20cm=1.25
$$
In my case distance beetwen middle and eye lenses was 20 cm, then L:
$$
L = d_{2}-f_{1}-f_{2}=20-5-5=10
$$
$$
m_{middle+eye}=(-L/f_{1})*(25/f_{2})=-10/5*25/5=-2*5=-10
$$
Then total magnification is:
$$
M_{total}=m_{objective}*m_{middle+eye}=1.25*10=12.5
$$

But i feel i am very wrong.

**UPDATE 2:**
I have learn a little bit about lenses and i have use lens equation for calculating angle magnification. But i am not sure that's right. Can someone say something about?

[image: lens equation]

Comment: First telescopes are always fond memories :-) Mine was a magnifying mirror from the bathroom, an eyepiece from my grandmother's bird-watching binoculars and a big old cardboard tube that was used for newsprint. Here's one way to do this; multi-element optical systems can be quickly analyzed to first order using simple 2x2 matrices for thin lenses and the spaces between them using [Ray transfer matrix analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_transfer_matrix_analysis). This would have six 2x2 matrices and you'd just multiply them out. It's a little tedious by hand, but it can be done.

Comment: this matrix analysis can support 2nd and higher order, the matrices are simply enlarged beyond 2x2 for the higher order terms e.g. $x^2, x \theta, \theta^2$ etc.